# Multiplying two lists leads to stack overflow

Tags: haskell

```
test :: [Int] -> [Int]
test l   | (length l) > 5 = l
         | otherwise = test l ++ take 1 searchSpace
    where searchSpace = zipWith (*) [100..999] [100..999]
```

The above code provides me with a stack overflow. I'm assuming that Haskell is fully evaluating and storing the result of zipWith in searchSpace. What would be the lazy way of creating this list, if I just want to have my program progressively apply `take 1`?

Comment: If you want to ask about stack overflow, do it on meta XD

Answer (score 6):

You have an infinite loop. If we pass a list like `[1..6]` (chosen so that length is greater than 5) to `test` it reduces like this:

```
test [1..6]
test [1..6] ++ take 1 searchSpace
test [1..6] ++ take 1 searchSpace ++ take 1 searchSpace
test [1..6] ++ take 1 searchSpace ++ take 1 searchSpace ++ take 1 searchSpace
...
```

The top of the evaluation tree becomes `(++)` in step two which must evaluate its left argument to proceed.

```
[]     ++ ys = ys
(x:xs) ++ ys = x : (xs ++ ys)
```

So the net result is that the function barely does any work at all and spends all of its time repeatedly diving into your infinite loop branch.

Comment: One follow-on question. I wrote this function as a test to see if searchSpace would let me take a new value each time it was called in the recursion (wasn't clear on how where clauses were treated in this instance). I see that it duplicates the initial 100*100 for every instance. What's the correct way for me have values that are taken stay taken?

Comment: There is no recursion for list size greater than 5. Infinite loop would be observed for size less than or equal to 5. Isn't it?

Comment: Oops, misread the function. I should have used `[1..4]` to trigger the bug.

Answer (score 1):

If l is <= 5, you are calling `test l` recusrively without a terminating condition.
You rather want something like

```
test :: [Int] -> [Int]
test l   | (length l) > 5 = l
         | null l = take 1 searchSpace
         | otherwise = test init_of_l ++ take 1 searchSpace
    where searchSpace = zipWith (*) [100..999] [100..999]
          init_of_l = init l
```

[working example here](http://codepad.org/n7WCpvcH)

Comment: What would `(l-1)` mean? Probably `tail l` would provide the intended behavior.

Comment: @Chris To get different count of elements everytime, you can check [this example](http://codepad.org/3vPcHbSR)